# Where do the different paths lead?

Tags: mmo-incremental

Near the beginning of the game, I can choose between the following three paths:

- Take the dusty path.
- Take the grassy path.
- Take the gravel path.

Does it matter which I choose?  Where does each one lead?  Can I eventually come back and take a different path?

Comment: I took the dusty path, which led to Presstown.  It seems like the path chosen determines which player hub you are grouped with.  Not sure if there is something special down the other paths.

Comment: I took dusty and ended up in Much Wenlock...

Comment: It looks like it's just random. I took the gravel path to Hungerford.

Comment: To expand on the data collection, I took grassy and ended up at Ivybank.